# More texts in same row with icon

Tags: html, css

I need more texts and icons in same row with html and css,
I need
[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCMrf.png).

Here is page: https://app.box.com/s/xpy18er6dyz5cm9jf4b01fa4jof7cxwx
(you must to download it)
How to do it?

Comment: can you show us some thing what you have done? html/css

Comment: That is the problem, i dont know what HTML elements to use.

Comment: What you got so far?

Comment: I created parallax page, link is in the question.

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML & CSS to your question. It's not fair to expect other StackOverflow users to download unknown .zip files onto their computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is something that you are looking for. It is responsive for you so you can be a bit flexible. I created a circle in css, but you can easily switch that out with an image or put it in the circle yourself.

https://jsfiddle.net/7r6gL7hc/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="description"> This is where you would put a description</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="description"> This is where you would put a description</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="description"> This is where you would put a description</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="description"> This is where you would put a description</div>
  </div>
</div>

CSS:

.container { max-width:800px; margin: 0 auto;}

.column { width: 25%; text-align: center; float: left;}

.circle { background: red; border: black 6px solid; border-radius: 50%; width: 150px; height: 150px; color: black; margin: 0 auto;}

.title { text-align: center; width:100%; font-size: 30px; padding: 10px 0; text-decoration: underline; text-transform: uppercase;}

.description { text-align: center; width: 100%; max-width: 100px; margin: 0 auto;}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! :)

Comment: no problem man, have fun

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use `div`. You can use css properties of `display` to make them align.

***Example***

https://jsfiddle.net/fpvctpjs/5/

Comment: Works fine, but how to make to 100% width? to set it in center